# Numlock key notification

Tags: windows-8, notifications, numlock

Is there any program I can use to have on-screen notification for the status of my numlock? My laptop keyboard does not have any LEDs for the numlock and I never know whether it's on or off without trying and checking. Something that displays numlock-on/numlock-off in notification area would be nice.

Comment: On which OS do you want this to run?

Comment: I run Windows 8

Comment: Now you can upvote =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't mention your operating system.

- Windows: [TrayStatus](http://www.binaryfortress.com/TrayStatus/) does exactly what you want.
- Linux: one option is [key-mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/), there's a .deb package in the download section

Comment: @sabrefresco if my answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted and/or upvote it. Thanks! :)

Comment: I cannot upvote yet but I marked it as accepted :)